# How to assign job equally in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I run my Spark program on 6 computers (1 master + 5 slaves) with 6 cores and 8GB memory each. I make 5 partitions and I want one partition is executed in parallel in 1 slave. So, every slave will have 1 task. But, when I run the program, 4 slaves did nothing and 1 slave did 5 tasks. How I know this things? I print something like "flag" to identify the working nodes then 4 nodes printed nothing and 1 nodes printed "flag" 5 times. Does anybody know what is going on and how to make it work like I want?

Following is my configuration"

```
spark-submit 
--class MainApp 
--master spark://172.23.8.8:7077 
--deploy-mode client 
--num-executors 5 
--executor-memory 6g  
--executor-cores 6 
--driver-memory 6g 
“C:\MyApps.jar”
```

Comment: Why do you care? I mean you have to treat your Spark cluster as a whole, it will distribute the computing if it has to, when it needs to. Also you may want to consider Yarn or something like that to visually see your jobs and tasks rather than relying on some print statements.

Comment: What I want is that in a node there is only one partition and then I will use multithreading to mine this sub dataset. Is it possible to assign 1 partition to one node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `spark.task.cpus` to the number of CPUs that a single node has.

Please note that although the distribution of tasks to nodes is a sort of round-robin, it's not deterministic and depends on task execution times, data locality, the `spark.locality.wait` parameter etc. See a quote from [Data Locality](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-locality) page below and [TaskSchedulerImpl.resourceOffers()](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSchedulerImpl.scala#L519) implementation.

> Spark prefers to schedule all tasks at the best locality level, but this is not always possible. In situations where there is no unprocessed data on any idle executor, Spark switches to lower locality levels. There are two options: a) wait until a busy CPU frees up to start a task on data on the same server, or b) immediately start a new task in a farther away place that requires moving data there.
>
> What Spark typically does is wait a bit in the hopes that a busy CPU frees up. Once that timeout expires, it starts moving the data from far away to the free CPU. The wait timeout for fallback between each level can be configured individually or all together in one parameter; see the spark.locality parameters on the configuration page for details.

The general guideline is to use a number of partitions that is 2x or 3x of the total number of CPUs in the cluster to better utilise the resources.

Alternatively, you can pass (row, preferred_host) tuples to the [SparkContext.makeRDD()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#makeRDD-scala.collection.Seq-scala.reflect.ClassTag-) function and process each partition using a narrow transformation mapPartitions() or the foreachPartition() functions. Please see [In Apache Spark, is there a way to force DataFrame execution on specific nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77643127/in-apache-spark-is-there-a-way-to-force-dataframe-execution-on-specific-nodes/77643550#77643550) for an example.

Also, please see the resources below for more information.

- Discussion [Number of CPUs per Task in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671832/number-of-cpus-per-task-in-spark).
- Page [Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling).
- Multi-threaded Reads section of the TileDB [Performance Tips](https://docs.tiledb.com/spark/performance-tips) page.
- [Why isn't a very big Spark stage using all available executors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55245841/why-isnt-a-very-big-spark-stage-using-all-available-executors/55246153#55246153), StackOverflow.
- [FAQ - When is it a good idea to set Spark locality wait to zero?](https://support.datastax.com/s/article/FAQ-When-is-it-a-good-idea-to-set-Spark-locality-wait-to-zero), DataStax.
- [BP 5.1.6 - Tune driver/executor memory, cores and spark.sql.shuffle.partitions to fully utilize cluster resources](https://aws.github.io/aws-emr-best-practices/applications/spark/best_practices/#bp-516-tune-driverexecutor-memory-cores-and-sparksqlshufflepartitions-to-fully-utilize-cluster-resources), AWS EMR Best Practices.
- [How to Optimize Your Apache Spark Application with Partitions](https://engineering.salesforce.com/how-to-optimize-your-apache-spark-application-with-partitions-257f2c1bb414/), Salesforce Engineering.

Comment: I have added --conf "spark.task.cpus=6". Now 2 nodes are idle, 2 nodes execute 2 tasks each, and 1 node executes 1 task.  I run several times and got the same pattern. The division is also random, sometimes Node 1 is idle or got 2 tasks or got 1 task. But yes the pattern is 0-2-1 (2 nodes-idle, 2 nodes-2 tasks each, and 1 node-1 task) like I mentioned before. Do you know what happen?

Comment: Did the nodes that had two tasks each execute them sequentially or in parallel? What were the task runtimes? Was the spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled parameter false?

Comment: Also, what cluster manager are you using?

Comment: Without this statement --conf "spark.task.cpus=6", 4 nodes were idle and 1 node executed 5 tasks in parallel. Now, with this statement, the nodes that had 2 tasks each executed them sequentially. The runtime is increased. The spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled set to false. How I know what cluster manager I use? I run my jar using package from https://spark.apache.org/.

Comment: I think I use standalone?

Comment: I see, that's interesting. Are all five workers/nodes started and visible in the master's web UI with the expected number of available CPUs and amount of RAM?

Comment: Yes, this is the information from web UI:

URL: spark://172.23.8.175:7077
Alive Workers: 5
Cores in use: 30 Total, 0 Used
Memory in use: 34.0 GiB Total, 0.0 B Used
Resources in use:
Applications: 0 Running, 10 Completed
Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
Status: ALIVE

Comment: Once I tried to create 15 partitions, then there were 15 executors created with 1 task each. Each node handled 3 executors. This condition is correct as expected. But why for my case which is only 5 partitions. It is not working properly.

Comment: I would expect Spark to create the same five *executors* because its number is fixed, 15 *tasks*, one for each partition, and each executor to execute three of those tasks.

Comment: `Now 2 nodes are idle, 2 nodes execute 2 tasks each, and 1 node executes 1 task.`
Could you please add a screenshoot of how that looks in the UI or wherever you see that, the query's code and how you created the five partitions to the ticket?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256227/discussion-between-edd-and-lionia-vasilev).

Comment: After some discussions, it works properly. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome!